# Time out prompt in imacros by using javascript

Tags: javascript, timeout, prompt, imacros

How could it possible in Imacros to assign default number to variable.

After time out 10 seconds if user doesn't change number with in 10 seconds ?

```
var n = prompt ( " Number of loops. " , 500 ) ;
```

Comment: It's not possible with `prompt` because it's synchronous (blocks execution of all further code until dismissed). You'll have to create your own prompt-like feature.

Comment: oh thanks! could you please advice how to figure out with this ? im a new in coding. thanks again.

Comment: If you're new to coding, there will be a lot to learn. [jQueryUI modal dialogs](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal) would probably help.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible because this control is integrated and built-in in the browser. It's not customizable. I'd advise against using if you have special needs.

You can do the same with [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/). I'm not sure if it has the timeout functionality, but even if not, you can close the FancyBox using its API.